# How can I store hypelink data in BigQuery and later get an activated link Google DataStudio.?

Tags: hyperlink, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, looker-studio

I am trying to build a dashboard which has hypelinks. I am storing the data in Google Bigquery as String. But I am not sure if I will be able to access the hypelinks in Google Data Studio.

I am expecting the results to be shown in Google DataStudio and hyper links should be enabled.

Comment: Hi Arkanil, Have you done a simple test in data Studio trying to display a dashboard with hyper links? If so can you please provide a screenshot of what's not working for you. BTW: I don't think this question is related to BigQuery it's very specific to Google data studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have URLs (hyperlinks) in your BigQuery data/tables, then Data Studio will try to infer them as such. If Data Studio can't, you can change the type of the dimension to `URL` anyway. See screenshots below. Data Studio correctly identified it as a `URL` and I was able to click it and it worked.

[image]

[image]